# backup restore sql database through AttachDBFilename

Tags: c#, sql-server, backup

I am not able to create a backup of database saved in location like `C:\database\mydb.mdf`

> error : Unable to create a backup

```
        Backup sqlBackup = new Backup();

        sqlBackup.Action = BackupActionType.Database;
        sqlBackup.BackupSetDescription = "ArchiveDataBase:" +
                                         DateTime.Now.ToShortDateString();
        sqlBackup.BackupSetName = "Archive";

        sqlBackup.Database = databaseName;

        BackupDeviceItem deviceItem = new BackupDeviceItem(destinationPath, DeviceType.File);
        //ServerConnection connection = new ServerConnection(serverName, userName, password);
        ServerConnection connection = new ServerConnection(serverName);

        Server sqlServer = new Server(connection);

        Database db = sqlServer.Databases[databaseName];

        sqlBackup.Initialize = true;
        sqlBackup.Checksum = true;
        sqlBackup.ContinueAfterError = true;

        sqlBackup.Devices.Add(deviceItem);
        sqlBackup.Incremental = false;

        sqlBackup.ExpirationDate = DateTime.Now.AddDays(3);
        sqlBackup.LogTruncation = BackupTruncateLogType.Truncate;

        sqlBackup.FormatMedia = false;

        sqlBackup.SqlBackup(sqlServer);   

 string dataBaseName = @"C:\database\mydb.mdf";    
 string serverName = @"Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;Integrated Security=True;User Instance=True";    
 string destinationPath = "C:\\mydb.bak";
```

Maybe I am passing wrong variables?

Please can anyone verify it and post me the right solution

thnx in advance.

PS: database is not password protected and can use mixed authentication

Comment: hey marc_s it is still giving error like this : Failed to connect to server Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;Integrated Security=True;User Instance=True.

Comment: error is thrown at line 'Database db = sqlServer.Databases[databaseName];'

Comment: Yeah - obviously - that's a totally bad connection string - it's neither a valid connection string for a server-based database, nor is it complete for an "attached-MDF" database scenario.... see my response

Answer (score 0):

First of all - I guess some of your parameters are wrong:

```
ServerConnection connection = new ServerConnection(serverName);
```

Here, you need to pass **just the server's name** - so in your case, do not send in your whole connection string - just `.\SQLExpress`

As for your database name - I don't know if you can use SMO to backup an "attached" MDF file in SQL Server - normally, this would be the database name (the name of the database **only** - no file name, no extension) when the database is **on the server**.

```
string dataBaseName = @"C:\database\mydb.mdf";
```

So my suggestion here would be:

- attach this MDF file to your SQL Server instance (which you have installed anyway)
- give it a meaningful name, e.g. `mydb`
- then use **just the database name** as your value here:

  ```
  string dataBaseName = "mydb";
  ```

With these points in place, your code does work just fine in my case, at least...

Comment: @j4m4l: use [SQL Server Mgmt Studio Express](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms365247.aspx) (a free download from MS) to attach your MDF to your server

Comment: @j4m4l: look at the SMO method `AttachDatabase` ([sample found on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms210158.aspx) )