# SQL Delete query not working properly

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2010, sql-server-2008

I had a logic error in my sql `delete` query which would not give any error in visual studio and did not delete the record in the database

Here is a snippet of my code

```
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(
   @"DELETE FROM table_name 
     WHERE item_id=" + itmIDs + 
         " AND vendor_id=" + vendIDs + 
         " AND dozen=" + selectedItmDzn + 
         " AND quantity=" + selectedItmQty + 
         " AND total_price=" + selectedItmTotPrc + "",
   con);
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

here is my conString

`SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Data Source=localhost;Initial Catalog=InvenotyBB;Integrated Security=SSPI")`

I have confirmed that the other verbs *(**select**, **update**, **etc**)* work, just not the specific command for **delete**.

Comment: Can you store the SQL in a variable and show the result of `Console.WriteLine(sql)`? Also can you check your connection string and verify that you aren't using silly and misleading features like `User Instance` and `AttachDbFileName`?

Comment: If you paste into sql server does that query run?  If you step through it do all the variable get filled out properly?

Comment: Is the table in your database named `table_name`?

Comment: @Pete if that is it I will fall over

Comment: also ... what happens if you replace that `DELETE` with a `SELECT *`?

Comment: @swasheck not much since it's `ExecuteNonQuery` <ducks>

Comment: @AaronBertrand ... was relying for a bit of lucidity from OP to be able to refactor appropriately

Comment: I beg of you to please check your connection string. If you are using `AttachDbFileName` your delete is working fine but you are checking the wrong copy of the database (since that connection string creates a *copy*).

Comment: Also change this to a `cmd.ExecuteQuery` [[ and use parameterized notation (not a huge deal here, since you're intentionally deleting, but still) ]] and check for return values and errors thrown. Don't rely on a thrown error alone.

Comment: @musa: As all are saying , 1st just check you connection string, also check if you where condition is true,

Comment: my condition is working fine i'm sure

Comment: @Musa and yet here you are on SO asking for help. One of these two is incorrect.

Comment: @jcolebrand what two what do you mean?

Comment: @Musa editing the Q like that won't get you much more of a result. Answering the questions that have been asked will. regarding "what two do you mean" I mean the two options: [Asking for help on SO] and [I know my query can't possibly be wrong, obviously I'm doing the right thing]. If you were doing the right thing, you wouldn't ask,.

Comment: How are you verifying the record is deleted? Have you opened the table in SSMS and verified the data is no longer there? Have you run profiler to see what happens? Have you run the command by hand?

Comment: Does your user have permissions to delete?

Comment: @Musa: when you come out with this , do let me know i was eagerly waiting for your solution :)

Comment: @Musa if you want to do something a little ... faster ... to try and resolve this, visit chat: http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/179/the-heap (this is a database pros chatroom)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given this original code (via my formatting):

```
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(
   @"DELETE FROM table_name 
     WHERE item_id=" + itmIDs + 
         " AND vendor_id=" + vendIDs + 
         " AND dozen=" + selectedItmDzn + 
         " AND quantity=" + selectedItmQty + 
         " AND total_price=" + selectedItmTotPrc + "",
   con);
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Let's change this to:

```
string deleteQuery = 
   @"DELETE FROM table_name 
     WHERE item_id=" + itmIDs + 
         " AND vendor_id=" + vendIDs + 
         " AND dozen=" + selectedItmDzn + 
         " AND quantity=" + selectedItmQty + 
         " AND total_price=" + selectedItmTotPrc + "";
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(deleteQuery, con); /* set a breakpoint here */
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Set the breakpoint and copy-paste that query to a comment here so we can see it.

Comment: or, y'know ... `Console.WriteLine(deleteQuery);` :)

Comment: You assume he's got a console to write to. Big assumption.

Comment: hence the smiley. i generally test my sql code in a console before moving it to the application - usually for this very reason.

Answer (score 3):

I can almost guarantee your connection string has:

```
User Instance=true;AttachDbFileName=|Data Directory|...something.mdf;
```

If this is the case, STOP DOING THAT. The AttachDbFileName feature actually creates a *copy* of your database file. So the one you have open in Management Studio or Visual Studio is different from the one your application created via the connection string. Your application deletes from the copy, there are no exceptions (because it worked), you refresh the original, and it looks like it didn't work.

See the answer from @marc_s's here:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/7222952/61305

If this isn't it, then I suspect either (a) errors are being ignored due to `try/catch` somewhere, or (b) your method for checking if the command worked is suspect. For example, if you are relying on a count, and the where clause matches zero rows, then the command *worked* but it didn't delete anything, therefore the count remains the same.

If neither of those are true, then goto line 1 of my answer. There is no magic here, a delete command will either affect 0 or more rows, or it will return an exception. Anything else can only be explained by improper troubleshooting / debugging.